# Changing multiple image extension using jquery

Tags: jquery

sorry, im new in jquery. I have this code on  tag:

```
<img class="fluidimage" src="img/picture1.jpg"/> 
<img class="fluidimage" src="img/goodimage1.jpg"/>
```

and i want to change all src on fluidimage class if the user resize their web browser. so my desired output is :

```
<img class="fluidimage" src="img/picture1_small.jpg"/> 
<img class="fluidimage" src="img/goodimage1_small.jpg"/>
```

and my question is how to put string "_small" before ".jpg" in jquery? I've tried to write jquery function but it isn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        function imageresize() {  
            var contentwidth = $('#container').width(); 
            if ((contentwidth) < '700'){ 
                $('.fluidimage').attr('src','img/picture1.jpg');
                $('.fluidimage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg', '_small.jpg'));
            } else {  
            $('.fluidimage').attr('src','img/picture1.jpg');  
            }  
        }  

        imageresize();     

        $(window).bind("resize", function(){  
            imageresize();  
        });  

        });
```

Please help!

Comment: It's not the best practice to do something on window resize.

Comment: yeah, i know. But can you help me with this one? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iterating it:

```
        if ((contentwidth) < '700'){
            $('.fluidimage').each(function() {

               $(this).attr('src','img/picture1.jpg');
               $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg', '_small.jpg'));

            });
        }
```

Comment: @ManseUK Why do you think so?

Comment: because `contentwidth` is a number and `'700'` is a string

Comment: @ManseUK ever heard of type coercion? Did you even test comparing those before commenting?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
var source = $(this).attr("src");
$(this).attr("src",source.replace(".jpg","_small.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((contentwidth) < '700')
{ 
   $('.fluidimage').each(function(){
       $(this).attr('src', str_replace(".jpg", "_small.jpg"));
   });
} 
else 
{  
   $('.fluidimage').each(function(){
       $(this).attr('src', str_replace("_small.jpg", ".jpg"));
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var usingsmall = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var contentwidth = $('#container').width();
        if (contentwidth < 700) {
            if (!usingsmall) {
                $('.fluidimage').each(function () {
                    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg', '_small.jpg'));
                    usingsmall = true;
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (usingsmall) {
                $('.fluidimage').each(function () {
                    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_small.jpg', '.jpg'));
                    usingsmall = false;
                });
            }
        }
    })
})
```

I have changed the code quite a bit !! You can use

```
$(window).resize(function () {
```

instead of `window.resize =` its an inbuilt [resize handler in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

The `if` statement was checking against `'700'` when you should be checking against a number (although it will work with `'700'`):

```
if (contentwidth < 700) {
```

and the final change is to iterate over the images with the class `fluidimage` and change each `src` attribute :

```
$('.fluidimage').each(function() {
```

this uses [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

And I have introduces a variable `usingsmall` this ensures that only necessary work is performed

Comment: Answering to why not, you can see from your solution. **Each** time the browser window changes the size so that `#container` width goes less then 700 (calculating `<div>` width takes CPU time), **each** image is replacing its `src` attribute, adding `_small.jpg` in progression.

Comment: @VisioN you are indeed correct there - i shall change my code to check .... but there is nothing wrong with using the resize event - your quote was "It's not the best practice to do something on window resize"

Comment: Nothing wrong, true, but I consider it as a bad practice, since it may bring a number of problems to you and to your CPU :)

Comment: Thank you so much ManseUK :) I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img.fluidimage').attr('src', function(i, oldSrc){
   this.src = oldSrc.replace('.jpg','_small.jpg');
})
```